# Rewrite Rule to Rewrite All EXCEPT File Extension

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I've got a rule setup to rewrite everything going into a subdirectory like so:

```
<rule name="Forms Directory" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^forms/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="forms.htm" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

However, I want to make a slight change to allow it to access an ASP file in the forms folder.  So I want to keep the same rule but exclude any .asp from matching the rule.  I tried the following but couldn't get it to operate as expected:

```
<rule name="Forms Directory" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^forms/(.*)[^(.asp)]" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="forms.htm" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An additional condition that checks file extension solves this.

```
<rule name="Forms Directory">
    <match url="^forms/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".+\.asp$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="forms.htm" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```