# Web Service call not working, just being redirected to the .asmx page

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a .Net web service I am working on. Locally everything works fine, as is usually the case. When I put the service into the site, compile the site, and load it onto the server it does not work. What happens is, if I browse the .asmx page locally on the server, and click a method to call, upon clicking invoke I get a new window with the .asmx page loaded. No XML output, nothing.

I copied the compiled site down from the server and the service works fine, so that tells me it's an IIS setting. The server is 2008 R2. Has anyone seen this issue before, or have any ideas of where to look? I have no errors in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I don't know if you found the issue, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314412/web-service-method-works-fine-on-development-computer-but-failed-on-server) had the answer for me, my rewrite included a rule to make the url all lower case. This causes the call to fail because the webservice method is case sensitive and included upper case characters. I added a rewrite rule to exempt .asmx files and it now works correctly (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618366/rewrite-rule-to-rewrite-all-except-file-extension)).