# Web service method works fine on development computer but failed on server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asmx, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have a serious problem with ASP.NET web service. I have a web service method that checks for the existence of user password in my project's database. I wrote the method inside an asmx file to access to it.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class CredentialsValidationService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]        
    public Boolean VerifyPasswordExistence(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            EventLogHandlers.WriteToEventLog("Call from WEB SERVICE", EventLogEntryType.Warning);                
            Boolean isValid = PasswordVerifier.checkPasswordExistence_byLoginInfo(
                UserInfoRetrievingClass.getUsernameByEmail(email), GlobalClass.getMD5Hash(MD5.Create(), password));

            return isValid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogHandlers.WriteExceptionToEventLog(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

It is supposed to return to me a boolean value. When I tested it on my local computer (Windows 10), it worked fine just as I expected. But when I deployed it to my company's server (Windows Server 2012), it didn't work. I've tried to test the web service on the localhost of the server but it doesn't work either. I even turned off the Windows Firewall of the server, placed a try..catch bloc (like in the above code) and then tried to test the web service on the localhost of the server by navigating to the web method page (ie. /credentialsvalidationservice.asmx?op=VerifyPasswordExistence), entering test email and password and pressing the Invoke button. Instead of showing an expected result (true or false) (like on my local pc), it jumped into the web service's description page /credentialsvalidationservice.asmx in a new browser tab. I checked the Event Log, and nothing in there. It doesn't give me any error detail to indicate what went wrong. Absolutely nothing in the Event Log.

To give you a bit more information about my project. It's written on Visual Studio 2013 and .NET Framework 4.5.1. The .NET Framework version on both my dev pc and my company's server is 4.5.1. The IIS version on my dev pc (Windows 10) is 10, while the on the server is 8.5. I wonder do I need to configure the server or install any plugin on the server to get this web service work? Please help. Thanks.

**UPDATED**: Finally I found the root cause of the issue. It is the URL Rewrite rule that I created for converting all urls of the website to lowercase. It converted even the name of the web method into lowercase and that caused the problem, because the method name is case sensitive. I just temporarily disabled the rewrite rule to get the service working. The service is placed in the path ~/Services of the root of the web app. I suppose I'll have to find some way to change the rule so that it'll affect only aspx files, but spare all asmx files (especially in the Services folder) from being lowered-case.

Comment: what do you mean that it doesnt work? you dont get a response or is the server not found or is there an exception?

Comment: Instead of returning a boolean value wrapped in a json message, it sent to me an entire html code of the web service description page when I call the method from client through ajax. And when I tested the method by navigating to the web method page (ie. /credentialsvalidationservice.asmx?op=VerifyPasswordExistence), entering test email and password and pressing the Invoke button, it opened a new tab on my Google Chrome and redirected to the web service description page (ie. /credentialsvalidationservice.asmx) on that tab.

Comment: I created another web service on the server

    public class TestWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

and the result is the same. When I pressed the Invoke button on the web service method page (ie. /testwebservice.asmx?op=HelloWorld), it opened a new browser tab and redirected that tab to the web service description page (ie. /testwebservice.asmx). I wonder do I have to configure anything for IIS 8.5 of Windows Server 2012 to make this works?

Comment: try this. why dont you return a string, instead of json then convert it to Json in your javascript code using JSON.parse. or just convert the value to boolean. i think you are getting an error because for json the format is {"property_name":"value"} where are you are only returning the value. so it cannot convert it to json

Comment: Finally I found the root cause of the issue. It is the URL Rewrite rule that I created for converting all urls of the website to lowercase. It converted even the name of the web method into lowercase and that caused the problem, because the method name is case sensitive. I just temporarily disabled the rewrite rule to get the service working. The service is placed in the path ~/Services of the root of the web app. I suppose I'll have to find some way to change the rule so that it'll affect only aspx files, but spare all asmx files (especially in the Services folder) from being lowered-case.